# Insert a <br /> tag after x words <a> using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any idea how make it with link? I try but nothing

```
<h3 class="wd-entities-title"><a href="#">WIANEK Amarylis bohaterem</a></h3>

$(".wd-entities-title").each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html().split(" ");
    html = html[0] + "<br>" + html.slice(1).join(" ");
    $(this).html(html);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nd46b23L/

Comment: Did you mean *after X words" - or after *first* word?   `.slice(n)` will *remove* the words up to `n` so your code (after fixing for the missing `a` selector as in the answers) will only work for "after first word"

Answer (score 3):

The text you want to separate is inside an `<a>` tag - you should include that in your query or else the first space you'll encounter is the space in the `<a>` tag.

```js
$(".wd-entities-title a").each(function() {
  var html = $(this).html().split(" ");
  html = html[0] + "<br>" + html.slice(1).join(" ");
  $(this).html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="wd-entities-title"><a href="#">WIANEK Amarylis bohaterem</a></h3>
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly less verbose approach using `html(function)` which will iterate over all instances of matching selector `<a>` exposing the current html for each instance

Then use `replace()` to insert the break at first space and return the modified string

```js
$(".wd-entities-title a").html((i, curr) => curr.trim().replace(' ', ' <br/>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="wd-entities-title"><a href="#">WIANEK Amarylis bohaterem</a></h3>
```